# Split Excel table over multiple PowerPoint slides

Tags: microsoft-excel, software-rec, microsoft-office-2007, microsoft-powerpoint

I have a table in Excel which is too long for one PowerPoint slide. So I would like to split it over 2 or 3 slides, but have the header on each of the slides. What is the easiest way to accomplish that? I am using Excel and PowerPoint 2007.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend printing to a PDF. You can customize how much data shows up on a page using the print dialog. By freezing the header row in the 'view' tab (ribbon interface), it will appear on each page printed. Then insert the PDF into powerpoint.

Answer (score 0):

From [here](http://www.ehow.com/how_5587507_copy-excel-powerpoint-windows-vista.html):

> **Step 1**
>
> Open the Excel spreadsheet with the data table that you want to copy by right-clicking on it and selecting "Open."
>
> **Step 2**
>
> Highlight the entire data table by clicking on cell A1 and dragging a box down and to the right across all of the cells in the table.
>
> **Step 3**
>
> Click the "Copy" button in the upper-left corner of the program. You can also copy the selection by holding down the "Ctrl" key and then pressing the "c" key.
>
> **Step 4**
>
> Open your PowerPoint presentation, and click on the slide where you want the table to be inserted. The slides are listed along the left side of the screen.
>
> **Step 5**
>
> Select "Insert," and then click on "Table."
>
> **Step 6**
>
> Click on the box in the upper-left corner of the table area to create a 1x1 table.
>
> **Step 7**
>
> Click on "Home," and then click "Paste." You can also hold "Ctrl" and then press "v" to automatically paste the copied table. The table will automatically be expanded from a 1x1 cell to the size of the copied table.

***( or )***

You could use [XPPORT](http://www.soft14.com/Business_and_Finance/Spreadsheets/XPPort_15318_Review.html), which can do this job.

> XPPort ports Microsoft Excel data to PowerPoint. A proven Excel add-in that views as a toolbar for use with all your spreadsheets and charts. When you are ready to convert Excel data to PowerPoint, XPPort reads your Excel page breaks and copies each page to a new separate slide.

[image]

Comment: It doesn't work, the table isn't split on multiple slides