# Stretch an Excel table in PowerPoint over multiple slides?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office-2007, microsoft-powerpoint

I work in a business where most people run on PowerPoint and wouldn't know what to do with an Excel sheet if it bit them. I need to regularly update a spreadsheet and put it into PowerPoint, but it takes up about 7 slides, requiring me to manually choose the slide breaks and moving things onto the following slide.

I feel that there must be a way to put a single table in PowerPoint (2007) and have it stretch over several slides automatically, but I can't figure out how. This question was previously asked but the answer does not cover the actual question:

> [Split Excel table over multiple PowerPoint slides](https://superuser.com/questions/68982/split-excel-table-over-mulitple-power-point-slides)

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I'd ask this on an excel forum.  There is just a huge disparity between average office users and the advanced Excel users.  It is mind boggling the macros they write.

Comment: @surfasb Thanks, I'll try to find an Excel forum.